# Assembly, Mips address out of range

Tags: assembly, mips, runtimeexception

I have to write a code that reverse a string in input.
I write this but I get:
line 38: Runtime exception at 0x00400080: address out of range 0x00000000.
May I have your help?
Thank you

```
.data
prompt:.asciiz"String:: "

str:.space 31

out:.asciiz"Reversed string: "

.text

.globl main

main: la $a0, prompt
      li $v0, 4
      syscall
      la $a0, str
      li $a1, 31
      li $v0,8
      syscall
      jal Reverse
      la $a0, str
      li $v0,4
      syscall
      li $v0,10
      syscall

Reverse: addiu $sp, $sp, -8
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        sw $a0, 0($sp)
        move $t0, $a0   #$t0 = first pointer
        jal Strlen
        li $t6, 1       #counter=1
        subiu $t1, $v0, 2  # $t1 = strlen - 2
        addu $t2, $a0, $t1  # $t2= last pointer
        div $t3, $v0, 2  # $t3 = strlen/2



Loop:   bgt $t6, $t3, Return # if t6 < t3 continue, else return
        lb $t4, 0($t0) # swap
        lb $t5, 0($t2)
        sb $t5, 0($t0)
        sb $t4, 0($t2)
        addiu $t6, $t6, 1 # counter++
        subiu $t2, $t2, 1 # last pointer-1
        addiu $t0, $t0, 1 #first pointer+1
        j Loop



 Return: lw $a0, 0($sp) 
         lw $ra, 4($sp) 
         addiu $sp, $sp, 8 
         jr $ra  

#Strlen gives me the lenght of the string

Strlen: li $v0, 0
Loop2:  lb $t0, 0($a0)
        beq $t0, $0, Ret     
        addiu $a0, $a0, 1
        addiu $v0, $v0, 1
        j Loop2
 Ret: jr $ra
```

The exception is in the function Reverse, in the loop, where I write: lb $t4, 0($t0)

Comment: Your `Strlen()` function clobbers `t0`, so after calling `Strlen()` in `Reverse()`, it no longer contains the address of the beginning of the string.

Comment: I understand! Thank you